# PHP Mail() Function injecting "@cp-in-3.webhostbox.net" with "from" address in feedback form

Tags: php, email, code-injection

I have been facing many issues while sending a mail through feedback form. First, the function was sending the mail while it was in the localhost. But after uploading it to the remote server, it stopped sending. Anyway, I fixed somehow. Now it is sending the mail, but injecting some more string to the "FROM" address. Please have a look at the code I have written and this what I am getting after receiving the email.

Code====>

```
<?php

    function putinplace($string=NULL, $put=NULL, $position=false)
    {
        $d1=$d2=$i=false;
        $d=array(strlen($string), strlen($put));
        if($position > $d[0]) $position=$d[0];
        for($i=$d[0]; $i >= $position; $i--) $string[$i+$d[1]]=$string[$i];
        for($i=0; $i<$d[1]; $i++) $string[$position+$i]=$put[$i];
        return $string;
    }

    $from1 = $_POST["email"];
    $from = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9@\.]/', ' ', $from1);

    $at_pos = strpos($from, "@");

    $from = putinplace($from, "\\", $at_pos);

    $subject1 = $_POST["subject"];
    $subject = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\']/', ' ', $subject1);
    $message1 = $_POST["body"];
    $message = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\']/', ' ', $message1);
    $to = "emailidtosend@gmail.com";
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers = 'From: abc.co.in' . "\r\n". 'Reply-To: emailidtosend@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= 'Content-type : text/html; CHARSET=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        echo "<script>alert('Email Sent Successfully. We will Get back to you Very soon.');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('contact-us.php', '_self');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Unable To Send The Email.');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('contact-us.php', '_self');</script>";
    }
?>
```

And Output===>

username\@gmail.com@cp-in-3.webhostbox.net (Look at the last portion of "FROM" address)

Comment: Why are you putting a ``\`` before the `@`? Can you print out `$headers` in your PHP script to see if your mailserver is mangling it?

Comment: This looks like you're using a web hosting package where your provider has the sending mail server configured to append a domain part to your sender address, effectively preventing you from spoofing any address that your provider's mail server is not responsible for.

Comment: If you want to get replies to your mail, add a `Reply-To` header instead and set it to `username@gmail.com`.

Comment: @Eric, I printed it out in the server and the output was only "username\@gmail.com" not "username\@gmail.com@cp-in-3.webhostbox.net";  Now why i have put \ before the @ is without this mail was sending from localhost perfectly, but not from the remote host. In order to fix that, I got to put this. Please help me bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
You do not need to put  via cp-in-9.webhostbox.net 
You need to configure you php.ini file in your web server.

Step 1. Find php.ini file
If it's not there then create one in home directory and add codes below

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail

this path "/usr/sbin/sendmail" is specific to server.
To get yours just create a php file with code 
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

and hit that file from web browser you will get the path value for key sendmail_path

One small and simple example for sending email in php is as :

<?php

// Set up parameters
$to = "Vivek.kumar@xyz.com";
$subject = "Your password";
$message = "<p>Hello Homer,</p>
<p>Thanks for registering.</p>
<p>Your password is: <b>springfield</b></p>
";
$from = "vivek@domainname.com";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\n";
$headers .= "From: $from" . "\n";

// Send email
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

// Inform the user
echo "Thanks for registering! We have just sent you an email with your password.";

?>
```

Comment: Code only is not a complete answer. Please explain yourself what you fixed and why you did it.